# angularjs directive with isolated scope doesn't parse variable in template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive:

```
angular.module('spApp.directives').directive("clickToEditPlain", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
        '{{value}} ' +
        '<a ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
        '<input id="{{inputId}}" type="text" name="{{inputName}}" ng - model="view.editableValue" >' +
        '<a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>' +
        ' or ' +
        '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEditPlain",
            ngModel: "=",
            inputName: "@",
            inputId: "@"
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
        }
    };
});
```

It works as expected. There is well parsed html on page where I can see properly evaluated `inputId` and `inputName`:

```
<input id="inputId-52" type="text" name="inputName-52" ng-model="view.editableValue">
```

But when I check a structure in debugger I see that name `inputName` evaluated in `{{inputName}}`:
[image]

Also the directive placed in ng-form.

Comment: This may be due to interpolation are not supported for generation of model controller. The model controller is created with this name `{{inputName}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your directive template:

```
template: function(elem, attrs) {
  return '<input type="text" name="' + attrs.class+ '">'
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div class="yourInputName" click-to-edit-plain></div>
```

Finally, this is not longer a problem in newer Angular versions.